# Apache on Debian - Upgrading to PHP8.1 - phpinfo() not showing new version and conflicts with mpm

Tags: php, apache, debian, sudo

I'm trying to update my server to use PHP8.1 and I ended up disabling http/2 and also can't figure out how to re-enable it and actually get PHP8.1 to run.

The first steps I did were:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.1
```

The second command had a conflict with mpm_event so I then ran:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

After running "sudo a2enmod php8.1" again as well as "sudo systemctl restart apache2", it seemed okay.

However, whenever I run "php -v", it says that the CLI is "8.1" but using "phpinfo()" on the live site still returns "7.4.26".

I also ran these commands which all show that 8.1 is currently running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phpize
sudo update-alternatives --config php-config
```

After all of this, I noticed that my webpages stopped serving via http/2. Upon trying "sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork" so I can enable mpm_event again, it says that it can't disable mpm_prefork because there's a conflict with the PHP module. When I disable the PHP module, I can disable mpm_prefork and enable mpm_event but then I wouldn't have PHP anymore (I think? It's all so confusing...)

Edit: I tried disabling the PHP module and enabling mpm_event but it made the website not work anymore so I reverted those changes.

For clarity, when I try "sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork", I get this error:

```
ERROR: The following modules depend on mpm_prefork and need to be disabled first: php8.1
```

If it helps, phpinfo() says that I'm currently running:

```
PHP Version 7.4.26
Server API  FPM/FastCGI
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.4/fpm
```

Also, I now have PHP8.1 in my mods_enabled folder and I swear there were no PHP modules at all there before all this.

All in all, I'm very new to server management but I simply want to run PHP8.1 (fpm version?) while using http/2 but am running around in circles and I also took a step back with accidentally disabling http/2.

Edit: My question is basically three parts:

1. Why did my site go offline after I disabled the PHP8.1 module? And,
   how do I prevent that from happening again?
2. How do I safely re-enable mpm_event (so that http/2 will work again)? Keep in mind that it seems to
   only be an option when both PHP8.1 and mpm_prefork modules are
   disabled.
3. How do I upgrade to PHP 8.1-fpm?

If an answer can provide steps for digging myself out of the hole that I dug myself into while also enabling PHP8.1-fpm then that would be awesome.

Oh, and just so it's clear; my current setup is:

- PHP8.1 and mpm_prefork modules are enabled (mpm_event is disabled)
- The live website is using PHP7.4-fpm without http/2
- The CLI version of PHP is PHP8.1
- I do not have PHP8.1-fpm installed

Comment: You are using php-fpm so try `a2disconf php7.4-fpm`, `a2enconf php8.1-fpm` and `systemctl restart php-fpm`

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep that in mind but I'd also like to get http/2 working again and don't understand why the site went down at that step in my original question.

Comment: Have you tried to disable php module now?

Comment: I don't want to try because I'm afraid the site will go down again. If I had a comprehensive list of steps and a back-up plan for how to reverse them, I'd try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your thrid question answers second, combined them into one list of commands

> Why did my site go offline after I disabled the PHP8.1 module?

When you switch off apache php module, web server treats php code as plain text, which is a default behavior for unknown content type. Its kinda working, but your code is not interpreted at all.

> And, how do I prevent that from happening again?

In order to prevent that either use [varnish](https://www.varnish-software.com/wiki/faq/index.html), load balancer([apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)/[nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)), make [snapshots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786229/making-a-snapshot-of-ubuntu) of the system when its stable or containerize your application with docker. Whatever will be suitable for your needs.

In varnish case it will create cached versions of your web pages and will return them in response omitting your webserver until no such cached version of web page exist(no cache hits in other words). But before, you need to write script which will cache all pages. Then varnish will simply send html responses.

In load balancer case if one node fail then it will redirect traffic to another alive node. Each node is basically a copy of your website.

Snapshots are images of your OS which you can use in different VMs for example. So if you messed up then you can simply delete snapshot and install initial one again.

In docker you can simply split your app into 2 services, which you can configure however you want without being afraid of making everything bad )

1 service will apache2

2 service will be php-fpm

Then you can simply build each service as an image and rotate images like in VM(Virtual Machine).

> How do I upgrade to PHP 8.1-fpm?

```
# step 1, optional if you did it before
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

# step 2, dont see any issues with simply installing newer version of php-fpm
sudo apt install php8.1-fpm

# check if user and group in php-fpm config are correct(/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf). 
# User and group should be the same as webserver user and group.
# if you want to check under which user webserver runs
# sudo ps aux| grep apache2 
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
# and also check if socket/port for php-fpm are created/opened and its running normally

# step 3
# disable modules and restart configured services. For apache better to reload instead of restart
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm
sudo a2enmod mpm_event
# optional in case its enabled
sudo a2enmod proxy
# optional in case its enabled
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm
sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm
sudo systemctl restart apache2
# manually set php version for CLI
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar8.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar8.1

# step 4
# Mask the old PHP-FPM daemon (tell the system to not start the old php-fpm daemon)
sudo systemctl mask php7.4-fpm
```

Hope that something in this list will be helpful )

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, when the site went down, nothing at all showed in the browser and Chrome dev tools showed a response code of "(failure)". Also, the shell said something about Apache not being configured properly. What I don't understand is that all I did was disable PHP8.1 module (which wasn't even enabled before all this) and mpm-prefork as well as enable mpm-event. Why would that completely screw up the site? Pretty sure everything was set like that when everything was working before I started tinkering around.

Comment: @user1413341 Enable also [error logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlog) for your website. Or just look into `/var/log/apache2/error` or similar path for more specific system errors. Probably something were either misconfigured or wasn't installed or enabled. Its also worth to check if `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php8.1-fpm.conf` has correct values just in case. Some modules relies on other modules. For example `mpm_prefork` relies on `php_mod` and it cannot work without. Probably you tried to combine non-working things :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a package named `php8.1-fpm` to be able to use the `mpm_event` instead of `mpm_prefork`. For example this is mentioned in [this tutorial](https://php.watch/articles/php-8.0-installation-update-guide-debian-ubuntu):

> Depending on the web server you use, you will need to install additional packages to integrate with the web server.
>
> For Apache using **mpm_event**, ..., php8.0-fpm package provides integration with PHP 8.0 via FPM.

Of course you will want the [php8.1-fpm package](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=php8.1-fpm).

Comment: Yes. My current setup is using PHP7.4-fpm but after stupidly disabling mpm_event, enabling mpm_prefork, and enabling PHP8.1 module, I can't seem to revert to my previous setup with mpm_event enabled considering there are conflicts. When I tried disabling mpm_prefork and PHP8.1 module and enabling mpm_event, the website stopped working. Now, I have PHP8.1 module enabled, prefork enabled, and the live site is using PHP7.4-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

In my Apache config I had to change this line to use the right socket:

```
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
          SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
  </FilesMatch>
```

Infos about the socket:

```
 # ls -l /var/run/php/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      5 Sep 22 12:42 php8.1-fpm.pid
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data  0 Sep 22 12:42 php8.1-fpm.sock=
```